# Sending Metrics: Spark to Graphite

Tags: apache-spark, monitoring, graphite

We managed to get Spark (2.x) to send metrics to graphite by changing the metrics.properties file as below:

```
# Enable Graphite
*.sink.graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
*.sink.graphite.host=graphite-host
*.sink.graphite.port=2003
*.sink.graphite.period=5
*.sink.graphite.prefix=my-app
```

However I noticed that we are getting only a subset of the metrics in graphite compared to what we get under Monitoring Web UI (http://localhost:4040). Is there any settings to get all the metrics (including Accumulators) in graphite?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: You do not enable sources. Like `.*.source.jvm.class`

Answer (score 0):

I use this library to sink user defined metrics in user code into Graphite: [spark-metrics](https://github.com/groupon/spark-metrics)

Initialise the metric system in driver side:

```
UserMetricsSystem.initialize(sc, "test_metric_namespace")
```

Then use `Counter` `Gauge` `Histogram` `Meter` like Spark `Accumulators`:

```
UserMetricsSystem.counter("test_metric_name").inc(1L)
```

For `Spark 2.0`, you can specify `--conf spark.app.id=job_name` so that in Grafana, metrics from different job run with multiple application id could have the same metric name. E.g. without setting `spark.app.id`, the metric name may include application id like this:

```
job_name.application_id_1.metric_namespace.metric_name
```

But with setting `spark.app.id`, it looks like:

```
job_name.unique_id.metric_namespace.metric_name
```